# Git for windows has stopped working

Tags: windows, git

Every time I am getting below error when I tried to pull from remote git to my repo.
Tried with different client but same error.I am using win7.
Can any one suggest what could be the problem ?

```
Error : Git for windows has stopped working.

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: git.exe
  Application Version:  1.8.4.0
  Application Timestamp:    5236e84e
  Fault Module Name:    bitguard.dll
  Fault Module Version: 2.6.1673.238
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5233288d
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 001793a8
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    16393
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Answer (score 2):

Do a search for `bitguard.dll`. It seems like some program you have installed is injecting itself into other applications. Crashes are not unexpected in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I found actual issue,In my machine there is antivirus which have bitgaurd.dll which is blocking git pull and push activities. So final solution for this issue is Antivirus. Just check by stopping antivirus software.