# "Git for Windows has stopped working" on Windws 7

Tags: git, bitbucket

My git suddenly failed on me. And it didn't just fail on one repo. It failed on ALL repo. It was working one minute, then after that it started to fail. When I git pull it shows "Git for Windows has stopped working" a couple of times.
And then it aborted the pull.

We have tried completely uninstalling and reinstalling git.
We have also deleted the `.gitconfig` file at the user folder.
We have also tried deleting the repository and then redownloading the file from bitbucket.
We have also tried system restore to no avail.

`git fsck` didn't work.

I am using a windows 7 for this thing. Heads-up, I have tried searching for a precedent for this problem, but I didn't see anything that matched with mine.

EDIT:
My git fails on all repos, even on newly made ones.
When I try git pull it gives me 2 "Git for Windows has stopped working" alerts and shows this on the console:

```
$ git pull
Cannot chdir to C:/xampp/htdocs/myProj, the toplevel of the working tree
git version is 1.8.4
```

Comment: What's your git version? Paste your complete error message is helpful for diagnosis.

Comment: updated: git version is 1.8.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually due to an external application recently installed or updated, and which interact badly with msysgit.

See for instance [this answer about an anti-virus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19187841/6309).

Check the [windows event viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/open-event-viewer) to see the full error message.

Comment: thanks. it worked. If I had more reputation i would've upvoted you on this. thanks. any ideas on a beter title for this so, more people can read on this page in case they have the same error?